# 1 is not the SameQ as Null, but why might 1 be Equal to Null?

Tags: symbolic, symbols, built-in-symbols, expression-test

The command

```
SameQ[1, Null]
```

returns

```
False
```

which is what I would expect, but the command

```
Equal[1, Null]
```

returns

```
1==Null
```

Why is Mathematica agnostic as to whether 1 is equal to Null ? Surely it is not ?

Comment: It does not evaluate if non numeric symbols are involved, unless both sides are exactly (full form) the same. "lhs==rhs returns False if lhs and rhs are determined to be unequal by comparisons between numbers or other raw data, such as strings. "

Comment: It's not agnostic: `Equal` only evaluates arguments if they have numeric or string values. `1==Automatic` and `Null == Automatic` are all left unevaluated. `1 == 1 + Null` is left unevaluated just as `1 == 1 + x` is, which perfectly makes sense, as you don't have a value for `x` (or for `Null`) yet. Think of it (as the doc states) that `Equal` tries to be as symbolic as possible, and does not evaluate symbols without values.

Comment: I think the deeper reason is that Mathematica does not treat `Null` as special in that case and thus behaves like it would for any unassigned symbol and returns unevaluated.

Comment: Food for thought: if things like `3 == x + 2` evaluated at once (or with any symbol in general like `Null`), we wouldn't be able to use them in functions like `Solve[]` and `Reduce[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`===` (`SameQ`) tests structural equality and is meant mainly for programming uses.  Like nearly all functions named as `...Q`, it evaluates immediately to either `True` or `False`.

`==` both *represents* and *tests* mathematical equality, and is meant for symbolic algebra use.

Thus when `==` is used with a symbol (or expression containing symbols) on either side, it will not evaluate. It stays unevaluated and it can be used to represent a mathematical statement.  This is how we write equations in Mathematica, e.g. `x^2 - 2 == 0`.

`Null` has no meaning in symbolic algebra uses so here it is just treated as a symbol, which it is.  Thus `1 == Null` stays unevaluated the same way `1 == x` does.

Mathematica is loosely typed: everything is an expression. You may put just about anything on either side of `==`. The nature of the language does not make it practical or worthwhile for functions to try to give a special treatment for each kind of object.  Since `Null` has no special meaning or use in symbolic algebra, it receives no special treatment from `Equal`.

Also consider that Mathematica will take things like `Solve[Null^2 == 2, Null]` with no complaint.

Comment: From the docs: *lhs* == *rhs* returns True if *lhs* and *rhs* are ordinary identical expressions. Thus, `==` yields `True` in some symbolic cases, like `x==x`, where `===` also yields `True`.

Comment: @JohnDoty Sure, and there are cases when it doesn't evaluate even though both sides are `NumericQ`. But the whole story doesn't fit in a single post.