# How do I verify an equality no matter the equivalent arrangement of the parts?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am a new user of Mathematica and have been trying to find a method for verifying equality. The issue that I keep running into is that nothing seems to work for all cases. Let me give you some examples:

- in: True === (x^2)/x == x
- out: True
- Good
- in:True === ab + b^2 + bc == b (a + b + c)
- out:False
- Bad
- in:True === FullSimplify[ab + b*b + bc == b (a + b + c)]
- False
- Bad
- in:(x^2)/x === x
- out:True
- Good
- in:Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] === Sqrt[x/y + y]
- out:Fals
- Bad

Is there any "one size fits all" type approach that will work for me. It just does not make sense to me how it says (x^2)/x is x but Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] is not Sqrt[x/y + y].

Comment: Try this `Reduce[a b + b^2 + b c == b (a + b + c)]` and `Reduce[Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] == Sqrt[x/y + y]]` .

Comment: Note `a b` not `ab`. In particular, `Simplify[a b + b*b + b c == b (a + b + c)]` works as desired.

Comment: (1) Note that `===` (`SameQ`) is for identical expressions, not mathematically nor computationally equivalent expressions. Thus `Simplify[Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] == Sqrt[x/y + y]]` but not `Simplify[Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] === Sqrt[x/y + y]]`. (2) I sometimes have more success with `Simplify[X - Y]` instead of `Simplify[X == Y]` (compare equal to `0`). (3) Simplification in Mma is an expression minimization problem, not a mathematical problem. It tries to make the expression tree as small as possible, using a finite set of transformations. It's not exactly the same as what is taught in algebra class.

Comment: Related: [(8796)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8796), [(159648)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159648), [(229204)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229204). Possible duplicate: [(115303)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115303)

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

See [Evaluating an If condition to yield True/False](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/evaluating-an-if-condition-to-yield-true-false) and the linked questions for a discussion of the difference between `===` and `==`. Don't use `===` for the OP's examples; use `==` instead. I'm discounting the apparent mistake writing `ab` without a space between the `a` and the `b`. Like in most programming languages, a string of letters without punctuation or white space signifies a single `Symbol` or "identifier".

Perhaps the only difference I see between [Testing equivalence of analytical expressions like $x^2 -x == x(x-1)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303/testing-equivalence-of-analytical-expressions-like-x2-x-xx-1) and this question is the role of autosimplification, which may explain why the question has not been closed. Since no one has voted to close yet, I will attempt to answer.
Sometimes autosimplification and simplification via `Simplify[]` and `FullSimplify[]` are confused and lead to a misunderstanding of when a particular simplifying step happens.

Here are the OP's examples with `Equal` replacing `SameQ` per the advice in the [linked Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303); `Simplify` works on all <s>five</s> three:

```
testEqual = {
  Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] == Sqrt[x/y + y],
  (x^2)/x == x, 
  a b + b*b + b c == b (a + b + c)
  (* , (x^2)/x == x,  <-- becomes the same the first *)
  (* Sqrt[(x + y^2)/y] == Sqrt[x/y + y]  (* ditto *)};

Simplify /@ testEqual
(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

The last question in the OP concerns autosimplification, in particular of the expressions `x^2/x` and `(x + y^2)/y`. As far as I know, neither the autosimplification rules nor the transformation rules used in either `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` are documented. So you have to get used to them. There's not much the user can do about autosimplify rules, except for a couple of options in `SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]`, neither of which apply here.

The first expression `x^2/x` has the `FullForm`

```
Times[Power[x, 2], Power[x, -1]]
```

There is an autosimplify rule that combines the product of powers that have the same base. This happens [notoriously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/why-does-mathematica-simplify-x-x-to1) for `x/x`, too.  So `x^2/x` first evaluates to `x`. The OP's comparison of `x^2/x` with `x` becomes a comparison of `x` to `x`. It does not matter whether `===` or `==` is used in this special case; both return `True`.

The second expression `(x + y^2)/y` has the `FullForm`

```
Times[Power[y, -1], Plus[x, Power[y, 2]]]
```

Any algebraic simplification involves rewriting the expression and testing whether the result is simpler -- and if not, you just wasted the user's time. Unlike combining like bases, there isn't a general rule that always simplifies this expression. Something similar can be said about the expression it is compared to, `x/y + y`. Sometimes users need the terms separated (hence `Expand[]`) and sometimes combined as a rational function (hence `Together[]`).  Neither expression should be autosimplified.  For the OP's comparison, one needs to use `Simplify` (and `Equal`!).